# how to run on array of string in nested loop in python

Tags: python, nested-loops, imageai

I try to run this code (small part of my program)
I fixed and added whitespaces and now I get new error, maybe this array does not fit to string?

```
arrayOfPhotos = ["1.jpg", "2.jpg", "3.jpg", "4.jpg"]

for name in arrayOfPhotos:
  detections = detector.detectObjectsFromImage(input_image=arrayOfPhotos[name], output_image_path="holo3-detected.jpg")

  for detection in detections: 
    print(arrayOfPhotos[name], " : ", detection["percentage_probability"])
```

I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dTEST.py", line 13, in <module>
    detections = detector.detectObjectsFromImage(input_image=arrayOfPhotos[name], output_image_path="holo3-detected.jpg")
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Can you help me?

Comment: Line which causes error expected to be indented.

Answer (score 1):

what you probably want is this:

```python
arrayOfPhotos = ["1.jpg", "2.jpg", "3.jpg", "4.jpg"]

for name in arrayOfPhotos:
  detections = detector.detectObjectsFromImage(input_image=arrayOfPhotos[name], output_image_path="holo3-detected.jpg")

  for detection in detections: 
    print(arrayOfPhotos[name], " : ", detection["percentage_probability"])
```

whitespace is important in python, for a statement to be part of a loop it needs to be indented vs the loop (I've added 2 spaces before the lines)

edit: the OP edited the question.

replace input_image=arrayOfPhotos[name] with input_image=name

Comment: Why do you use 2 spaces? [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation) recommend to use 4.

Comment: @Olvin Roght Personal preference. Some people use tab characters, I use four spaces myself.

Comment: The question clearly shows a `TypeError` rather than an `IndentationError`, so I don't see how this answer is relevant.

Comment: @ekhumoro The question's edit history clearly shows an `IndentationError`.

Comment: @superbrain Exactly - it's history, so not relevant.

Comment: @ekhumoro Not sure I follow. Are you blaming the answerer instead of the question vandalizer?

Comment: @superbrain My comment was meant to prompt an update to this answer - which it did.

Answer (score 0):

```py
arrayOfPhotos = ["1.jpg", "2.jpg", "3.jpg", "4.jpg"]

for name in arrayOfPhotos:
    detections = detector.detectObjectsFromImage(input_image=name, output_image_path="holo3-detected.jpg")

    for detection in detections: 
        print(name, " : ", detection["percentage_probability"])
```

The array of photos is a list not a dictionary...